# MySQL right join slow performance

Tags: performance, indexing, mysql-5.7, right-join

I have two tables:

Restaurants and SurveyInvitation.

One restaurants has many survey invitation.

I want to select all the restaurants that have a survey invitation and the status of it is 'approved', 'completed', 'hidden_review' .

The restaurants table has ~1400 rows and the survey invitation ~2.4 milion rows.

This is my query

```
SELECT  `Restaurant`.`id`
FROM   `restaurants` AS `Restaurant`
RIGHT JOIN `survey_invitations` AS `SurveyInvitations`
           ON ( `SurveyInvitations`.`restaurant_id` = `Restaurant`.`id`
                AND `SurveyInvitations`.`status` 
                IN (
                    'approved', 'completed', 'hidden_review'
                   ) 
               )
WHERE  `Restaurant`.`country_id` = 53
AND `Restaurant`.`area_id` IN ( 1, 16, 27, 118,
                                   219, 221, 222, 223,
                                   224, 225, 230, 231,
                                   235, 236, 237, 238,
                                   239, 240, 248, 226,
                                   241, 244, 246, 227,
                                   245, 228, 229, 242,
                                   243, 249 )

group by `Restaurant`.`id`
```

This runs in 1.235 sec.

Running explain gives

https://jsfiddle.net/bjuepb9j/3

I also tried this but no luck still 1.2 sec

```
SELECT  `Restaurant`.`id`
FROM   `db_portal`.`restaurants` AS `Restaurant`
RIGHT JOIN  (
    select `restaurant_id` from `survey_invitations` AS `SurveyInvitations`
    where `SurveyInvitations`.`status` 
    IN ('approved', 'hidden_review', 'completed')
)  AS `SurveyInvitations`
ON (
`SurveyInvitations`.`restaurant_id` = `Restaurant`.`id`
)
WHERE  `Restaurant`.`country_id` = 53
AND `Restaurant`.`area_id` IN ( 1, 16, 27, 118,
                                   219, 221, 222, 223,
                                   224, 225, 230, 231,
                                   235, 236, 237, 238,
                                   239, 240, 248, 226,
                                   241, 244, 246, 227,
                                   245, 228, 229, 242,
                                   243, 249 )

group by `Restaurant`.`id`
```

Explain is the same.

In the fiddle there is also the result from show index on both of the tables.

1.2 sec for a ~2.4 million rows is to much I think.
Maybe the indexes are wrong, I'm not that good at this kind of stuff.

Edit.1.
https://jsfiddle.net/bjuepb9j/6/

Has show create table and show columns of survey_invitations

Comment: Can you share your table create statements with indexes and (primary/unique keys)?

Comment: Why are you using a `RIGHT JOIN`?  With a right join, the table on the right 's join criteria will never be null (because null does not equal null), which means the `Restaurants` table is optional, but then you negate that in the `where` clause by doing equality checks against the `Restaraunts` table (country_id and area_id).  I think an inner join would be simpler.  Try that and see how it impacts performance.  (inner joins offer more options for optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM restaurants r
WHERE r.country_id = 53 AND
      r.area_id IN (1, 16, 27, 118, 219, 221, 222, 223,
                    224, 225, 230, 231, 235, 236, 237, 238,
                    239, 240, 248, 226, 241, 244, 246, 227,
                    245, 228, 229, 242, 243, 249
                   ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM survey_invitations si
              WHERE si.restaurant_id = r.id AND
                    si.status IN ('approved', 'completed', 'hidden_review') 
             );
```

Then, for this query you want indexes on `restaurants(country_id, area_id, id)` and `survey_invitations(restaurant_id, status)`.

A `right join` is entirely unneeded for your query.  The `where` clause turn it into an `inner join` anyway.  In all likelihood, the expense of the query is in the `group by`.  This version eliminates that.

Comment: Works in 0.6 sec.
And thanks for exists, is the way since I don't need the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing the join with an IN subquery, and not an EXISTS subquery.
When writing the query with an IN subquery, you avoid the correlated EXISTS query, which can occasionally be slower (depending on the amount of results).
Try this:

```
SELECT
        r.id 
    FROM
        restaurants r 
    WHERE
        r.country_id = 53 
        AND r.area_id IN (
            1, 16, 27, 118, 219, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 230, 231, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 248, 226, 241, 244, 246, 227, 245, 228, 229, 242, 243, 249
        ) 
        AND r.id IN (
            (
                SELECT
                    si.restaurant_id 
                FROM
                    survey_invitations si 
                WHERE
                    1 = 1 
                    AND si.status IN (
                        'approved', 'completed', 'hidden_review'
                    )
            )
        )
```

For this query, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `restaurants` ADD INDEX `restaurants_index_1` (`country_id`, `area_id`, `id`); 
ALTER TABLE `survey_invitations` ADD INDEX `survey_invitations_index_1` (`restaurant_id`, `status`);
```